# (Some) radio buttons not clickable in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following works just fine in any browser*

*except IE...

```
<div class="radio-groups">

    <fieldset class="radio-group diameter" id="diameter">

        <div class="option hidden"><span>DIAMETER</span></div>

        <input type="radio" id="radio-01" name="diameter" value="1.75">
        <label class="option" for="radio-01"><span>75mm</span></label>

        <input type="radio" id="radio-02" name="diameter" value="3.00">
        <label class="option" for="radio-02"><span>85mm</span></label>

    </fieldset>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <fieldset class="radio-group volume" id="volume">

        <div class="option hidden"><span>VOLUME<small>WEIGHT / LENGTH</small></span></div>

        <input type="radio" id="radio-04" name="volume" value="500">
        <label class="option" for="radio-04"><span>500cm&sup3;<small>(calculating)</small></span></label>

        <input type="radio" id="radio-05" name="volume" value="1000">
        <label class="option" for="radio-05"><span>1000cm&sup3;<small>(calculating)</small></span></label>

        <input type="radio" id="radio-06" name="volume" value="2000">
        <label class="option" for="radio-06"><span>2000cm&sup3;<small>(calculating)</small></span></label>

    </fieldset>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <fieldset class="radio-group spool" id="spool">

        <div class="option hidden"><span>SPOOL</span></div>

        <input type="radio" id="radio-08" name="spool" value="standard" checked>
        <label class="option" for="radio-08"><span><img src="/img/spool.svg"><br/>Standard<br/>&nbsp;</span></label>

        <input type="radio" id="radio-09" name="spool" value="eger">
        <label class="option nothin" for="radio-09"><span><img src="/img/spool.svg"><br/>Eger</span></label>

        <input type="radio" id="radio-10" name="spool" value="drem">
        <label class="option" for="radio-10"><span><img src="/img/spool.svg"><br/>Drem<br/>&nbsp;</span></label>

        <input type="radio" id="radio-11" name="spool" value="stan">
        <label class="option" for="radio-11"><span><img src="/img/spool.svg"><br/>Stan<br/>&nbsp;</span></label>

    </fieldset>

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

And it looks like this:
[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7uw6r3g0whaqlqh/Clipboard01.jpg]

When I click inside 'diameter' cells, either on text or area around text -- it gets selected,
when I click inside 'volume' cells on text, it doesn't get selected, but when I click on area around text -- it gets selected,
when I click inside 'spool' cells on text, it gets selected, on image, it doesn't get selected [ignore incorrect image proportions here], on area outside image or text -- it gets selected.

And my question is quite simple: how can I debug this?

There's click even attached to the first two fieldsets, but it's exactly the same without it.

Comment: Do you have a live example somewhere?
The pure HTML you put here works for me in IE with selecting by pressing on whatever. Might be some CSS messing with you.

Comment: @FabianMiiro unfortunately the server is behind NAT, so can't show live demo... but it looks like it's actually a problem with click event.
Commenting out this:
`$('#volume').click(function() { .. });`
allowed me to click on text in 'volume'.
Just not sure why this works in every browser except IE.
Looks like some other click takes over this click...
Thoughts?

Comment: May I ask what version of IE are you using? And also what version of jQuery?

Comment: Sure. jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.1. IE 11 on Windows 8.1.